# How (hadoop) reducer get sorted values with python streaming?

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

Example:

Maps' output:

```
key1, 3
key1, 1
key1, 2
key1, 4
```

In the reduce which handles `key1`, I want the reducer gets input in this order:

```
key1, 1
key1, 2
key1, 3
key1, 4
```

Comment: the streaming using '\t' for default delimiter(I suppose you are changing it to , here). the sort phrase will automatically use the first split part as key. so it seems there is no good way for that. but why do that ? you can collect all the key1's value in the reduce and sort it there, if the number of key1 is not that large

Comment: @michaeltang key1 is large... can't sort in a list.. I try your way at the first and just find the memory is not sufficient for storage key1

Comment: I think this might work,but I can not give it a test, try add this param  -D mapreduce.partition.keycomparator.options="-k1 -k2n"  refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468482/hadoop-sort-input-order